# python script to test I/O on C program

Tags: python, c, io

I have a code in C and I want to write a script in python that read input from a file (input.txt for example), run the C code with that input and write the output into another file (output.txt for example).

How can I do it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you need a Python script, and that pipes are not enough? On Linux, for example, you can do this exact thing as following: `yourprogram < input.txt > output.txt`. The `<` pipes a file to stdin (input), the `>` pipes stdout (output) to a file.

Comment: Take a look at the `subprocess` module.